# MPMoviePlayer unable to play video stream from a url without extension

Tags: iphone, url, video, video-streaming, mpmovieplayer

I am trying to play a video(mp4) file from a url with MPMoviePlayer (e.g.: http://localhost/api?file_id=2313mk) but unable to get it working, wonder if there is any solution.

Few tests are done as below:
1) Play url in computer browser : **SUCCESS**
2) Play url in iphone(4.2+) browser/ MPMoviePlayer : **FAILED**
3) Copy file and rename, then play in iphone browser/MPMoviePlayer from the new url with extension (e.g.: http://localhost/video.mp4): **SUCCESS**
4) Check header for Content-Type(video/mp4) : **EXISTS**

Response headers for url without extension: (e.g.:http://localhost/api?file_id=2313mk)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Download accepted
Date: Tue, 29 Mar 2011 04:48:03 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Length: 24897567
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

Response headers for url with extension: (e.g.:http://localhost/video.mp4)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 29 Mar 2011 04:11:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8l DAV/2 PHP/5.3.4
Last-Modified: Fri, 18 Mar 2011 05:38:16 GMT
Etag: "d1b78c-17be81f-49ebb2f458200"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 24897567
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

Comment: it actually works for mp3 format, if server url(e.g.:http://localhost/api?file_id=2313mk) returns a mp3

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development-advanced-discussion/15768-mpmovieplayer-video-via-url-glitch.html

Comment: it is different problem, the above stated problem is movie player can't play from the url (e.g.:http://localhost/api?file_id=2313mk)

Answer (score 0):

Your test results suggest that **"video/mp4" MIME type is not recognized**. Video with filename extension is played regardless of Content-Type, because extension "mov" is known to belong to a movie file:

> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH9-SW6

Can you change Content-Type?

Comment: The Content-Type seems correct actually, but why/what do you suggest to change?

Comment: Sorry, I've done only "download and play" or HTTP Live Streaming. First one works based on filename extension and second works after server starts sending correct MIME types. Haven't done dynamic downloading (yet), but guess I would try "video/mpeg" or "video/quicktime". Change mime type at server side, I mean.